# How to Identify whether the current column is editable in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

In kendo grid , i want to insert/add new row when TAB key is pressed from last editable column. Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use **grid.addRow()** which adds an empty row.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.addRow();
```

You will have to bind the keyUp action from the last editable column to get the "Tab" key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My grid has template fields and column reorderable is enabled. Please reply how can i find the last editable column using javascript?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this problem?

Comment: try this selector:

$('#grid tbody tr').on('keyup','td:last-child',function(){ 
//Check if it is Tab hit, etc...
}

Comment: Thanks Balder, but thats not working. It would be helpful atleast if i get current cell id or current cell's column index.